# Bootstrap4.4: make two column grid responsive

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, grid-layout

I'm using Bootstrap 4.4.1

I tried to create 2-column layout: Image on Left and Text on Right.

```
<section class="resume-section-first p-3 p-lg-5 d-flex align-items-center" id="about">

        <div class="w-100">
            <div class="block">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="w-50">
                        <div class="span4">
                            <img class="img-left w-100" src="/img/profile-lg.jpg"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-50 p-5">
                        <div class="span4">
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="content-heading">
                                    <span>Software Engineer</span>
                                    <h2>Test Title</h2><br>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Experienced Software Engineer in developing Web Application, as well as building robust RESTful API.
                                    Expert in System Architecture Design, Development and Maintenance of Software systems.
                                    Equipped with a diverse and promising skill-set required in the market.
                                    Proficient in various platforms and languages. Able to effectively self-manage during independent
                                    projects, as well as collaborate as part of productive team.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

On Large screen, the above code is displayed in 2-columns. But on small screen I want to show Full Column for Image and Text. I tried to use w-md-100 or w-xs-100 but not working.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Why aren't you using the grid layout classes: `col-sm-*`, `col-md-*` ... your question is the ideal use case for this. The columns will occupy all 12 columns on small screens and on sizes >= 768px it'l occupy 6 (of 12 columns) i.e. 50% width; [more info here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

**working snippet** below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section class="resume-section-first p-3 p-lg-5 d-flex align-items-center" id="about">

  <div class="w-100">
    <div class="block">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
          <div class="span4">
            <img class="img-left w-100" src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/Jumbo.jpg" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
          <div class="span4">
            <div class="content">
              <div class="content-heading">
                <span>Updated</span>
                <h2>Test Title</h2><br>
              </div>
              <p>
                Experienced Software Engineer in developing Web Application, as well as building robust RESTful API. Expert in System Architecture Design, Development and Maintenance of Software systems. Equipped with a diverse and promising skill-set required in the
                market. Proficient in various platforms and languages. Able to effectively self-manage during independent projects, as well as collaborate as part of productive team.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```